# jQuery .mouseleave not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace a user name with a logout button on hover.  When the page loads, I have this as one of the nav. elements...

```
<li id="logout_name">
    <span class="nav_icon_sizing hidden-xs no_focus" style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 8px; color: white;"><?php echo ucfirst($user->data()->fname); ?></span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get the text to toggle to become a logout icon with this...

```
$('#logout_name').mouseover(function(){
    $('#logout_name').replaceWith('<li id="logout_name"><a href="<?=$us_url_root?>users/logout.php" class="nav_icon_sizing hidden-xs no_focus" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="Logout" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i></a><li>')
});
$('#logout_name').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#logout_name').replaceWith('<span class="nav_icon_sizing hidden-xs no_focus" style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 8px; color: white;"><?php echo ucfirst($user->data()->fname); ?></span>');
});
```

When I hover over the name, it does change to the logout icon, but...

1. It won't change back to the user name when I mouse out, and
2. The fancy bootstrap tool tip doesn't display properly for the logout icon.  I get the standard HTML tooltip instead.

I feel like if `$(document).ready()` could some how be re-called one `mouseover`/`mouseleave` all would be well, but I don't think that's a real thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you should be doing is setting the `.text()` *content* of the element. And you don't need to perform the DOM selection over and over. `$(this).find("span").text("...new data...")` or something.

Comment: ...frankly, I think you should probably take a step back and figure out a better way to solve the problem. Seems like you have a couple elements that will be created over and over again the way you've chosen it. Usually better to just show and hide the elements instead.

Comment: @rockstar: That was my first plan, but when I do that kind of thing (w/o replacing the `<li id="logout_name">`), the logout icon continually flashes when hovering over it, like it's getting reloaded continuously. AND the mouseleave doesn't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before long, you can achieve everything you need by simply using CSS and the `:hover` pseudo.
Now to JS

---

Use `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`.

`mouseover` triggers whileever (made up this word) the mouse is **over** your element.

You could instead:

```
$('#logout_name').on({
  mouseenter: function () { /*enters code here */ },
  mouseleave: function () { /*leaves code here */ }
});
```

Also, the way you replace `<li>` with `<span>` raises suspicions you're doing something wrong in there. `<ul>` accepts `<li>` elements only, not SPANs.

**The important issue here** is that you're **replacing** a DOM element with a new one, therefore the newly created element will no longer respond to your events - since it was bound to the now removed one

Using `.on` with Dynamic Event delegation might (not) help here:

```
$(document /*or some static parent selector */ ).on({
  mouseenter: function () { /*enters code here */ },
  mouseleave: function () { /*leaves code here */ }
}, '#logout_name');
```

A better example to prevent entering infinite loops due to recreating the same element and attaching new events all over again is to only modify it's content using i.e: `.html()` but keep the original `<li>` wrapper:

```js
$('#logout_name').on({
    mouseenter: function () { 
        $(this).html('<a>ENTER</a>');
    },
    mouseleave: function () { 
        $(this).html('<a>LEAVE</a>');
    }
});
```

```html
<ul id="settings">
  <li id="logout_name">
    <a>LEAVE</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

P.S: Don't use inline styles. Use your stylesheet.

Comment: *"mouseover triggers whileever (made up this word) the mouse is over your element."* It triggers once upon entering the element as well as any descendant elements. That'll have the effect of just performing the same replacement over and over. It doesn't affect the `mouseleave`, which will only happen once when leaving the bound element. The real issue is the replacement.

Comment: ...and don't suggest delegation on the document. That's really inefficient, especially with a `mouseenter/leave` event.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan: Replacing using .html() was my original plan, but when I do that, the logout icon continually flashes when hovering over it, like it's getting reloaded continuously.  AND the `mouseleave` doesn't work.  I tried your code and it doesn't work on my end.  I have no idea why though.  Thoughts?

Comment: BTW, I began working w/ `:hover` originally, but I don't think it can display HTML... can it?

Comment: Don't know why, but having the thing to change being the link text (i.e. `<a href="#">link text</a>`) seems to have made this work.  Still marking this as the accepted answer though b/c I used the code.